# Is it possible to simulate the effects of high altitudes for plants?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, environment, growth

Note- I considered asking this on gardening.stackexchange.com but i believe it is better suited for this site since it deals with more complicated material.

As I understand it, certain plants (*Camellia sinensis*, *Coffea*, etc.) grow best at higher altitudes. What factor, biologically speaking, is responsible for this?

I know that the oxygen concentration at higher altitudes is lower, is this the reason?

If so, is it possible to use machinery to alter the gas concentrations in a grow room and simulate the effects of high altitudes? Are there any other factors such as pressure or anything that can also be altered? Would simulating this environment be practical for large scale applications?

Comment: The higher altitude means lower atmospheric pressure which in turn means lower oxygen concentration. Just pumping the air out of a sealed chamber would simulate this. Temperature, humidity and sunlight intensity/composition should also be taken into account.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's known which factor is responsible for this. Altitude changes the air pressure, but it can also drastically change the temperature, rainfall, drainage, soil type(no silt on mountaintops), etc. You can simulate almost anything with varying degrees of difficulty, but most would be impractical for fields on fields of crops.